# Knockout JS binding element's property to another element

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am trying to bind my selected category's `guid` property to another `ko.observable` element. I need to hold that data value in order to send it to the server in a correct `JSON` format.

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bsx54x8/)**

I am stucked at the binding *selected category's guid* value to *SelectedCategoryGuid* in order to appear in `JSON` file like

```
'SelectedCategoryGuid': 'guid1'
```

I have tried `$data` and `$root` bindings in the `HTML` but couldn't achieve it.

Comment: I'm reading only *i want* and not *i'm stuck*. Can you also share the problem?

Comment: I am stucked at binding selected data's value to another object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: Remove the quotes around your `value` data-bind. You should pass a reference to an observable here, not the name of a property.

```
value: Info.SelectedCategoryGuid
```

Now, you'll see your guid paragraph print: `[object Object]`. That's because it's storing the whole category, not just the `Guid`.

**Step 2**: To only store the `Guid` property, use the `optionsValue` binding. This binding works similar to the `optionsText` binding you've already used:

```
optionsValue: 'Guid'
```

Now things start working as intended. You'll notice the initial `bla` value gets cleared, because it does not appear in your data set.

Here's the two changes in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/40sh1vjj/